# Sorting DataTable consists of string of Integers and Chars

Tags: c#, string, sorting, datatable

I have a `DataTable` with column `CourseNr` of type String with following values:

```
"121"
"111"
"108"
"122"
"BH20"
"PHD45"
"ADH90"
```

I want to sort CourseNr column (Integers in ASC order) and (Chars in ASC alphabetically order)like this:

```
"108"
"111"
"121"
"122"
"ADH90"
"BH20"
"PHD45"
```

I know There can be many possible suggestions to solve this, But I need some best possible approach to achieve this?

Comment: So some approach of what you have tried and then we can help fix it

Comment: In  what order should `"X9"` and `"X10"` be sorted?

Comment: Its no matter, just in alphabetically order if its a mix of ints and chars like: "PHD45"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the windows-builtin natural-sort(like f.e. files are ordered) [`StrCmpLogicalW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb759947(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Compares two Unicode strings. Digits in the strings are considered as numerical content rather than
>   text. This test is not case-sensitive.

```
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
internal static class SafeNativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);
}

public sealed class NaturalStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string a, string b)
    {
        return SafeNativeMethods.StrCmpLogicalW(a, b);
    }
}
```

Then the code to sort the `DataTable` is easy with LINQ:

```
table = table.AsEnumerable()
  .OrderBy(r => r.Field<string>("CourseNr"), new NaturalStringComparer())
  .CopyToDataTable();
```

(credits for `NaturalStringComparer`  to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/248613/284240)

Comment: This is the best possible way!! Thanks Tim